# Vuetify Breakpoint vs CSS Helper Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have seen different examples posted inside of the Vuetify documentation or code snippets around the internet that refer to either a Vuetify breakpoint or a CSS helper class in regards to marking an element reactive to the screen size.

Is there a standard or recommended practice, or even a small performance difference to determine when I should use one or the other?

For example:

```
<p v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.hiddenMdAndUp">...</p>
// vs
<p class="hidden-md-and-up">...</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS helper class relies purely on the browser and its processing of media queries.
I would bet it's much faster than a piece of javascript which will be always behind `v-if`.

Moreover, if you really need to use a piece of javascript to make some element visible or hidden, in Vue it's preferred to use `v-show` (it uses a `display` property of the element instead of adding/removing from DOM as `v-if` does). See for [spec](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show) details.

Comment: Would it be safe to caveat this with saying `v-if` is preferred for any "heavy" components - ones that add a lot of nested DOM elements or run anything non-trivial (e.g. heavy computations, API calls, etc.)? Although `v-show` and preferably CSS should be used to hide/show simple components, they won't stop the mounted & created life cycles and subsequent listeners & function calls.

Comment: A logic to make a decision is a bit different. `v-if` is a heavy operation by its nature (it manipulates with the DOM). Adding/removing heavy components to the DOM is havier than show/hide them.
Hence, you have to use `v-show`/CSS when a component's visibility will be frequently triggered. E.g., you want to show/hide something by clicking on a Show/Hide link. But `v-if` can save you from adding something unnecessary to the DOM at all when the condition to trigger the visibility is rare. E.g., there is a component visible only when you an admin (visibility triggered only at re-login).